# Pyplot figsize attribute values resize plot for Series but not dataframe with subplots = True

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Here are two plots:

One plot is a pandas series (ao). The code resizes the plot using pyplot. The second plot (aonao), is a pandas dataframe combining AO and NAO series.The code sets subplots attribure to 'True' and uses the same figsize dimensions, however the dataframe does not resize? Here's the graphic from jupyter notebook. Not sure of this is notebook issue or a pyplot issue? Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create subplots (in aonao) with `subplots=True`, pandas needs to create a new figure and ignores your previous figure creation. You have to pass the figsize to the `plot()` function.

```
aonao.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(15,6))
```